# Rails layout not rendering properly?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, ruby-on-rails-4

Recently I picked up a Rails project from another developer.

When I start the Rails server on my Mac, the layout is not rendering normally:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>My title</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="/assets/store/reset.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
```

The `<head>` tag is closing too early, and is followed by the body tag, which makes all the `<meta>` tags and stylesheets outside the head.

However, when one of my colleague starts the server on his PC the layout renders properly.

---

Here's one of my layouts:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= render 'spree/shared/head' %>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
</head>

<body>  
  <div id="container">
    <%= render 'spree/shared/header' %>

    <div id="main" role="main" class="clearfix">
      <aside id="sidebar" role="complementary" data-hook> 
        <%= render 'spree/shared/menu_left' %>
      </aside>

      <div id="content">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= render 'spree/shared/footer' %>
  </div> <!--! end of #container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us some code. are you sure you are running the same code?

Comment: Yes we are using the same code

Comment: Are you using different browsers?

Just put things that should be in the head in the head.

Comment: As you can see in my layout everything is suppose to be in the head. And it's not a client side problem because if I access his server it renders properly and when his access mine it doesn't

Comment: @GuiGreg There's probably a syntax error in the `render 'spree/shared/header'` - check that file. Different browsers render differently. You didn't specify which browsers are problematic. This is probably unrelated to ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found it ! The error was created by a weird behaviour with Spree layout and Nokogiri.
Here's the solution : https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/2633

In my Gemfile I've set nokogiri version to 1.5.9 like this :

```
gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.9'
```

Comment: Nice, looks like that issue is a bit better documented than the one I found. Or at least has a lot more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a known issue, documented [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/3059). In that thread, Ryan Bigg stated:

> I believe this is a problem with using Nokogiri with an older version
>   of libxml. Can you please make sure that you're using the absolutely
>   latest stable version of libxml?

Try to update your [`libxml`](http://xmlsoft.org/) version to see if that makes a difference.